# Bundling and Minification in a Angular SPA application created in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, angularjs, visual-studio, bundling-and-minification

We have an angular SPA application which is created in Visual Studio 2015. In the visual studio, this is an MVC application. We have Layout.cshtml and all content pages are regular HTML pages. We are using angular routing to navigate between different pages. How can we use Visual Studio bundling and Minification in regular HTML pages?

Comment: I have done this a few months ago but I was limited only to the index page to load all the necessary resources and load constants from the server to expose it to the front end

Comment: I also read this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1033076/Integrating-AngularJS-with-ASP-NET-MVC even though this solution is working I thougth this is an overkill

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio ASP.net projects can use gulp as the default template managers, read:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/using-gulp.html

The document mentions the project is core version of dotnet but its not really required.

You are going to have to use [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) + [Tools for visual studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/node-js-vs.aspx).

You can Install Gulp by yourself:

```
npm install gulp -g
```

1. The first step is to **Add GULP as a package dependency**(along with its packages):
http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2014/10/08/how-to-use-gulp-in-visual-studio.aspx

```
npm install gulp --save-dev
npm install gulp-concat --save-dev
npm install gulp-cssmin --save-dev
npm install gulp-uglify --save-dev
npm install rimraf --save-dev
npm install gulp-htmlmin --save-dev
```

2. Edit **gulpfile.js** to add the required dependencies(examples used
    here are CSS, JS and HTML):

```
"use strict";
var gulp = require("gulp"),
rimraf = require("rimraf"),
concat = require("gulp-concat"),
cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
htmlmin = require("gulp-htmlmin");
var paths = {
    webroot: "./wwwroot/"
};
paths.js = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.js";
paths.minJs = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.min.js";
paths.css = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.css";
paths.minCss = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.min.css";
paths.html = paths.webroot + "html/**/*.html";
paths.minHtml = paths.webroot + "htmlmin/**/*.html";
paths.concatJsDest = paths.webroot + "js/site.min.js";
paths.concatCssDest = paths.webroot + "css/site.min.css";
```

3. Final step is to add gulp tasks by editing the second half of **gulpfile.js** to add the required tasks:

```
gulp.task("min:js", function () {
  return gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
    .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min:css", function () {
  return gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
    .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});
gulp.task("min:html", function () {
  return gulp.src([paths.html, "!" + paths.minHtml])
    .pipe(htmlmin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});
gulp.task("min", ["min:js", "min:css", "min:css"]);
```

4. After you are done you can either run `gulp min` by command line or setup
    a task runner schedule(not sure if it works with pre core versions
    but worths a try), if not, you can manually schedule a pre or post
    build task via the environment available in project properties:

[image: Select task runner]

[image: Assigned tasks in build phase]

[image: Assign task to build phase]